# Criar rotas com múltiplos parâmetros no CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-amigável, rotas

Tenho um projeto desenvolvido em Codeigniter e estou configurando algumas rotas para ficar com algumas URLs agradáveis, porém acabei encontrando um problema.

Em uma determinada rota, não sei a quantidade de parâmetros que ela vai vir, poderá vir com 1 parâmetro ou até mesmo com 4 parâmetros. No arquivo `routes.php`, como eu configuraria para reconhecer esses parâmetros?

Nesse exemplo funciona, mas creio que não é o correto:

```
$route['vendas/(:any)'] = '$1';
$route['vendas/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/$2';
$route['vendas/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/$2/$3';
$route['vendas/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/$2/$3/$4';
```

Comment: Amigo, não seria o caso de fixar uma rota e enviar os parâmetros por POST ?

Comment: Nesse caso especifico não, como por exemplo, estou acessando uma rota `vendas/detalhes`, mas posso ter a rota `vendas/ativas/detalhes/id/5`

Comment: Creio que esse link ajude: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html